# .Net-like IntelliSense for VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Up until now in VC++, when I want to see everything I do :: . This shows all of my objects. Is there a way to make it like c# so it checks as you type without needing :: . Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a free way to do this, but you could check out [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Until vs 2010 comes out ill use this

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ctrl+Space` to force intellisense to display itself.

Intellisense doesn't do a good job sometimes for C++ projects. They've fixed it's problems, but unfortunately the fix is only available in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual C++ IDE in Visual Studio does not have the option "Show completion list after a character is typed," which is the specific option from C# that you're referring to. However, you can manually bring the completion list up at any point by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I'm a VA addict. However, Visual Studio comes with Intellisense...? (VA is just waaay better)